# Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener from onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-navigation

I want to set an onclicklistener in the `onBindViewHolder` in order to navigate to a different fragment and send along some data to that fragment.

For the life of me, I can't seem to find a way to make it work. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

The adapter class:

```
class ListAdapter(private val list: List<Workout>): RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkoutViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int{
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WorkoutViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return WorkoutViewHolder(layoutInflater, parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WorkoutViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val workout: Workout = list[position]
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val id = workout.workoutId
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("workoutId", id)
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.workoutDetailsFragment)
        }
        holder.bind(workout)
    }
}
```

I can get the toast to pop up, so the onclicklistener seems to be working. However, the navigation part does not work.
If I just set a button inside the fragment that is hosting the recyclerview and add `button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.workoutDetailsFragment))` it can navigate just fine. So the problem seems to be calling the navigate function from inside the onclicklistener inside the onbindviewholder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener()` creates an `OnClickListener`. Creating an `OnClickListener` just to never set it on anything doesn't do anything.

Instead, you'll want to just trigger your `navigate()` call directly, doing the same [one line of code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/Navigation.java#119) that `createNavigateOnClickListener` does internally:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WorkoutViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val workout: Workout = list[position]
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val id = workout.workoutId
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("workoutId", id)

        // Using the Kotlin extension in the -ktx artifacts
        // Alternatively, use Navigation.findNavController(holder.itemView)
        holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.workoutDetailsFragment, bundle)
    }
    holder.bind(workout)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking at how to use the `findNavController()` method but couldn't get it to work. I needed that `holder.itemView`before it. Thanks a lot and appreciate the help!

Comment: If this helped answer your question, make sure to accept the answer to move the question out of the unanswered queue. Best of luck going forward!

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign your created listener rather than using it inside of a lambda. When you use a lambda with `setOnClickListener()`, the lambda literally is your listener. So in your example, you're creating a listener, but it's never assigned anywhere.

So to instead assign the created listener from `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener()`, your code should look like `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.workoutDetailsFragment))`